# How to get daily count with date in last 7 days in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I am create one query for the get daily last 7 days user followers count in the sql server. and i am write one query but not given expected output the table. right now just give the count in last 7 days not give the with the date. here below write my query and tell me where is my mistake.

This is my query =>

```
DECLARE @my_date DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
SELECT  
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(InsertDateTime AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, -7, @my_date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS date1Count,
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(InsertDateTime AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, -6, @my_date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS date2Count,
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(InsertDateTime AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, -5, @my_date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS date3Count,
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(InsertDateTime AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, -4, @my_date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS date4Count,
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(InsertDateTime AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, -3, @my_date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS date5Count,
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(InsertDateTime AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, -2, @my_date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS date6Count,
SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(InsertDateTime AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @my_date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS date7Count
FROM
UserFollower
WHERE
InsertDateTime BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
```

Current output =>

```
date1Count | date2Count | date3Count | date4Count | date5Count | date6Count | date7Count
 10            05           20           10           30            50          40
```

Expected output =>

```
Expected o/p =>

DateColumn | Count
09-05-2017    10
08-05-2017    05
07-05-2017    20
06-05-2017    10
05-05-2017    30
04-05-2017    50
03-05-2017    40
```

any one know how can do that this task in sql server please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `APPLY` like this

```
SELECT CAST(dateadd(day, T.i, getdate()) AS Date) AS DateColumn, uf.TotalCount 
FROM (VALUES (0), (-1), (-2), (-3), (-4), (-5), (-6)) AS T(i)
OUTER APPLY 
(
   SELECT Count(InsertDateTime) AS TotalCount
   FROM UserFollower
   WHERE Datediff(day,UserFollower.InsertDateTime, dateadd(day, T.i, getdate())) = 0 
) uf
```

Comment: Hello @Triv can you please help me one with your solution?

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: SELECT CAST(dateadd(day, T.i, getdate()) AS Date) AS DateColumn, uf.TotalCount 
  FROM (VALUES (0), (-1), (-2), (-3), (-4), (-5), (-6)) AS T(i)
  OUTER APPLY 
  (
     SELECT COUNT(UF.InsertDateTime) AS TotalCount
     FROM userfollowers UF
     INNER JOIN user U on U.UserId = UF.UserFollowerId
     WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,UF.InsertDateTime, DATEADD(DAY, T.i, GETDATE())) = 0 and UF.IsFollowed = 1 and U.IsMUser = 1 and U.IsFUser = 1 
  ) uf

Comment: i am write this query and today i want 8 count need but getting this query 0 count so please can you help me where is my mistke

Comment: in my database today i have 2 user follow by 4 user so 4*2 = 8 count so query return 0 count

Comment: can you please help me where is my mistake and what is problem in the query

Comment: Does dour sub-query in `Apply` clause return any result for today?

Comment: I think your data is not correct for one of conditions in inner join: `UF.IsFollowed = 1 and U.IsMUser = 1 and U.IsFUser = 1`? Please check it. I don't see any problem with your query.

Comment: yes but i need add for inner join and also add this condition in where clause show how can mange this cnd

Comment: You don't use anything in User table except checking. If you want follow- user MUST BE suitable for those conditions, then use inner join and 0 is corrected number.

Comment: Hello triv can you please help on sql in one query on xml with i have post the question so can you please help me

Comment: I saw your question and give an answer, you could check it. :)

Comment: Hello triv can you please help me on sql server in one query?

Comment: Hello triv can we know please with this solution how to generate date with 2 - 2 days in periods. for ex like 20-6-2017,23-6-2017,26-6-2017

Comment: You need a recursive cte like this `;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT '2017-06-20' AS CurrentDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(day, 3, c.CurrentDate) FROM cte c
    WHERE CurrentDate < '2018-01-01' -- you must have a stop condition
)
SELECT * FROM cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`

Comment: i am asking question this is my post id "44669249" can you please see and give me some hint on that please help me

Answer (score 1):

can't **GROUPBY** clause be used at the end of your query?

```
GROUP BY DateColumn
```

Comment: where can you please tell me?

Comment: At the end of your query

Comment: Sorry I meant to say GROUP BY

Comment: no in this query not the need group by and with you idea please give the answer so i can do that your wave? please

Comment: and please see the my expected output i want to date also with so that time not used group by

Comment: do something like this

SELECT DATECOLUMN,SUM(COLUMNTOSUM) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE CONDITION
GROUP BY DATECOLUMN

Comment: please see above answer